# unable to set path of images in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I moved my wordpress website from one folder to another. and i changed the path in admin panel settings also.  Everything is working expect images in slideshow.

I clicked on empty image area in chrome and inspect element. i found that, Path is not changed for images.

Example: `test.domain.com`     Folder: `public_html/test/mywebsite/` 
movied to : `mywebsite.com`  Folder: `public_html/mywebsite/`

Where should i set the path in wordpress ?

HTML

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url(http://mywebsite.com/home/javed001/public_html/test/mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/Photoshopped-Grilled-Black.jpg); ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find/replace URLs in the database for media URLs and URLs in post content. Some URLs may be in theme options, too.

Use phpmyadmin at your host - or install it yourself or use the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/ - and search for the old URL with phpmyadmin's find function.